# Como acceder al estilo de una fila en un ListView de WPF desde c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

estoy enlazando una lista de numeros desde c# al ListView en WPF con ItemsSource.
Lo que quiero hacer es setear el estilo de una fila en particular (ej: cuando el numero = 0) y pintarla con un color. Esto lo quiero hacer desde el backend pero no lo estoy logrando.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Usa un Converter, por ejemplo:

```
public class ValueToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value == 0 ? Color.Red : Color.Green;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Y haz un Binding entre el background de tu fila y el valor de la celda.

Edit:
Si no haces un binding puedes hacer un style trigger:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Cantidad}" Value="0">
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
 </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Creo q no me expresé bien... quiero saber como acceder a la propiedad q maneja el estilo de las filas. Pq una vez sepa como accesarla podré setearla o consultarla. Gracias